# What is the term for the 'Moksha'? The last birth for the soul, it'll not take birth anymore

Tags: word-request, word-usage

In Hinduism, we believe that when a body dies, the soul goes up and then takes (re?) birth. The (re?) birth could be of anything. Say, if I die, depending upon my sins and meritorious deeds, I'll take birth as an insect, fish, dog or even a human.

Hindu sages and gurus have specified the ultimate solution to get rid of the cycle of rebirths. It is called as the [***Moksha***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moksha) The soul is then with god and free from taking any birth. That's it. The story is finished. This makes the soul divine and free from joys and sorrows. This was an ultimate goal of those sages then.

Wikipedia explains it in a sentence using some words but still does not define ***one*** term.

I'm not sure whether this theory exists in any religion, and thus may not get **the exact term** but in English, anything close to this will work.

Comment: Arguably, you're talking about *nirvana*, but I'm sure that you already know the word.

Comment: @DamkerngT. of course yes! I know that word but it's not English! In my mother=tongue too it's nirvana!

Comment: The whole concept of rebirth is strange and exotic in Western society since Greek and Roman civilisations. Judeism and Christianity do not include the Hindu idea of rebirth _at all_. Pre-existing European cultures (before Christianity) did not include this kind of concept. Why would there be any word for such a specifically Hindu / Buddhist concept in a language that never had to deal with it? In these cases, the words are simply borrowed from a language that _does_ have the concepts, like [nirvana](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/nirvana), that is simply an English word by now.

Comment: I know to describe the belief that has been existing since thousands of years, English simply adopts the original word but then whether or not any term available is the question. All *yoga postures* now have English names! :)

Comment: @MaulikV, and yet we call yoga *yoga* instead of using an historically English word for it. Sometimes when we encounter a foreign concept we adopt a loan word. Other times we find a way to use English words to describe it. In the case of yoga postures, probably it was felt by yoga teachers that it would be easier to learn the poses with new English names than to learn dozens of "foreign" words for them.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on a website about Hinduism.

Answer (score 1):

As this concept does not exist, to the best of my knowledge, in any Western religion, we don't have a "native" word for it. It's certainly not part of Christianity, Judaism, Islam, or Graeco-Roman beliefs. (There may have been some less-popular religions in the west that believed such a thing, but if so, I'm not familiar with them.)

You can use the word "nirvana", but in English that has come to mean "a state of great happiness" rather than specifically reflecting the Hindu religious belief. I suspect most Westerners would not relate it to the idea of cycles of rebirth. But that's probably the correct word in some technical sense.

When English speaking people want to describe this concept, they typically say "escape from the cycle of rebirth". That is, you have to use a phrase rather than a single word.

Of course if you were writing a book or article about Indian beliefs, you could clarify what you mean by "nirvana" or introduce some other Hindu term and then use it consistently.